# How do you resolve Duplicate title/meta tags on pages with pagination? What are the Best practices?

Tags: php, html, seo

Google webmaster tools reports `Duplicate title tags` on pages where I have pagination.

A few example are linked here.

```
HTML suggestions
Duplicate title tags
Your title provides users and search engines with useful information about your site. Text contained in title tags can appear in search results pages, and relevant, descriptive text is more likely to be clicked on. We recommend reviewing the list and updating the title tags wherever possible.
« Back to all issues
Pages with duplicate title tags Pages
Licitatii publice Romania din domeniul licitatii produse petroliere si combustibili
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina18.html?sort_field=data_licitatie&sort=asc
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina30.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina32.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina33.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina34.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina35.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina36.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina37.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina37.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina38.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina38.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina39.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina39.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina4.html?sort_field=data_licitatie
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina4.html?sort_field=nume
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina40.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina40.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina41.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina45.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina46.html
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina6.html?sort_field=nume
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina8.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7-pagina9.html?sort_field=valoare_estimata
/licitatii-publice-ro/licitatii-produse-petroliere-si-combustibili-7.html
```

What steps do you do to fight this issue? How do you set your title/meta tags to be different on the paginated pages.

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: put page X of Y in the tile of do what most of us, including google do -nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the pagination in the title. For example: "Example Store | Bjorn Borg Underwear | Page 2 of 20". [Take a read here](http://www.epiphanysolutions.co.uk/blog/the-impact-of-pagination-on-seo/). although less important - the same can be done for the description meta tag.

Answer (score -1):

The `title` and `meta` tags should be database driven, each page must be showing some different information so pull out the information from database and populate the title tag. However another approach if each of page have relevant information then you probably don't want Google to index each page, switch between pages using Ajax calls, Google bot will not be able to crawl all your pages except the first page.

Comment: Since this is a problem of pagination, I don't have different information in the database to pull for each page.

Comment: when you are rendering each page you must have some unique information regarding that page, e.g. if you are showing different cities on different pages then show start and end city name on tile of that page e.g. `cities Chicago to XYZ` and change this info on second page and so on.